# Two external monitors, only mirroring

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've a Dell XPS 9360 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

The laptop only has one usb-C port. I connected a dock HUBEE Station Plus, which should enable multiple desktops. In fact it has 1VGA,1HDMI ports.

If I connect the dock with the laptop and two monitors, they only mirror each other.
If I run xrandr, I see eDP-1 (the internal one), DP-1 connected, DP-2 disconnected.

So the two external monitors are connected to DP-1, and mirror each other. In fact, In the settings, I see only two desktops and not three.

Is there a way to make them independent, i.e., having monitor 1 on DP-1 and monitor 2 on DP-2? Note that one exit is VGA and the other is HDMI.

Many thanks,
micV

Comment: Have you checked ubuntu display settings? There should be a way to configure mirroring and enable/disable monitors.

Comment: Sounds like that is how this dock treats the 2 monitors. That is a question you may want to ask the maker of the dock.

Comment: Thank you David. Yes indeed, I was ripped off. The package says: 'multi-screen', but actually it can't treat the two external monitors in an independent way. 

The thread can be closed, I think.